# How do I define these functions?

Tags: python, encryption, function

After one of my last questions was not-so-well-received, I decided to take into account all answers for that question (duh, right?). One that is stumping me is defining/calling a simple function.

I understand the main idea, and can do it on a small (simple) scale. For example:

```
def multiply(x, y):
     return x*y

numb1 = 2
numb2 = 3

print(multiply(numb1, numb2))
```

Simple. Now what I'm trying to do is clean up my Vigenere cipher by defining the functions, and what's stumping me is what parameters to use and why. I don't want to change the (possibly poorly-written, don't make fun) code, however I just want to see how it would look after making use of defined functions.

```
message = input("Enter a message to encrypt:\n").upper().replace(" ", "")
print("Enter your encryption key ("+str(len(message)),"or less letters.): ")
key = input().upper().replace(" ", "") 
div_times = int(int(len(message))/int(len(key)))
remainder = int(len(message))%int(len(key))
key_ring = (((key)*(div_times+1))[:-(len(key)-remainder)])
alph = 26 

print("-------\n"
      "Message:  ",message,"\n"
      "Key:      ",key_ring,
      "\n-------")
mvalues = [0]*len(message)
kvalues = [0]*len(key_ring)
m_position = 0
k_position = 0

for letter in message:
    mvalues[m_position] = ord(letter)
    m_position += 1

for key in key_ring:
    num = alph - (int(ord("Z")) - int(ord(key)))
    kvalues[k_position] = num - 1
    k_position += 1

m_position = 0
k_position = 0
print("\nEncrypted message: ", end="")
for character in message:
    newletter_v = (mvalues[m_position] + kvalues[k_position])
    if newletter_v > ord("Z"):
        newletter_v -= 26
    elif newletter_v < ord("A"):
        newletter_v += 26
    print(chr(newletter_v)+"", end="")
    m_position += 1
    k_position += 1
```

I've tried a combination of things and I keep getting errors or an incorrect output:

```
def encryptMessage(message, key):
    mvalues = [0]*len(message)
    kvalues = [0]*len(key_ring)
    m_position = 0
    k_position = 0
    for letter in message:
        mvalues[m_position] = ord(letter)
        m_position += 1

    for key in key_ring:
        num = alph - (int(ord("Z")) - int(ord(key)))
        kvalues[k_position] = num - 1
        k_position += 1


message = input("Enter a message to encrypt:\n").upper().replace(" ", "")
print("Enter your encryption key ("+str(len(message)),"or less letters.): ")
key = input().upper().replace(" ", "") 
div_times = int(int(len(message))/int(len(key)))
remainder = int(len(message))%int(len(key))
key_ring = (((key)*(div_times+1))[:-(len(key)-remainder)])
alph = 26 

print("-------\n"
      "Message:  ",message,"\n"
      "Key:      ",key_ring,
      "\n-------")
mvalues = [0]*len(message)
kvalues = [0]*len(key_ring)
m_position = 0
k_position = 0

encryptMessage(message, key)

m_position = 0
k_position = 0
print("\nEncrypted message: ", end="")
for character in message:
    newletter_v = (mvalues[m_position] + kvalues[k_position])
    if newletter_v > ord("Z"):
        newletter_v -= 26
    elif newletter_v < ord("A"):
        newletter_v += 26
    print(chr(newletter_v)+"", end="")
    m_position += 1
    k_position += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give is to always think of a function in terms of its **inputs** and **output**.

The parameters are the inputs and what the function returns is the output. In the case of your cipher, think about what can vary (and needs to be supplied as opposed to the things that are always the same) - these are the inputs:

- the message to encrypt
- the encryption key

You can write the declaration for the function and then fill in the body:

```
def encrypt(message, encryptionKey):
    """encrypts message using vignere cipher"""
    # TO DO in here perform encryption to produce 
    # the return variable encryptedMessage...
    return encryptedMessage
```

When defining functions always try to take something that is likely to be used more than once in your program and encapsulate it. By creating a function `encrypt` you can then perform the operation repeatedly but only write the code once. This is the DRY principle - which stands for **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.